# Determine if output is stdout or stderr

Tags: linux, stdout, stderr

How can I determine if what a process is outputting is stdout or stderr?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are only three ways I know of to determine what a program will output to STDOUT and what to STDERR

1. Read the documentation. Or
2. Experiment with redirection†
3. [print STDERR in red](https://serverfault.com/q/59262/55524)

†For example:

`program > program.stdout 2> program.stderr`

Then look at the two output files to see what the program has written to STDOUT and what it has written to STDERR.

Instead of redirection you can pipe to `tee` if you need output to continue to the screen as well as into a file. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/692000/477035

Comment: I usually use a variation of option 3: `program | grep .` prints STDOUT in red.

Comment: Printing in red is pretty much exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks RedGrittyBrick & Dennis

Answer (score 12):

Based on your commented request:

```
{ { command; } 2>&3 | sed 's/^/STDOUT: /'; } 3>&1 1>&2 | sed 's/^/STDERR: /'
```

Comment: Looks impressive. But would you mind to add the cherries to your tree, and explain what it is doing? Not everybody around here is a guru -- and your construct is quite a little complex ;)

Comment: The brackets are for ordering.  I actually got that exact form from I-forget-where, but the point is to use extra file descriptors (beyond 1=`stdout` and 2=`stderr`) to take the output of the inner set of brackets, and run `stdout` through one `sed` command, while `stderr` goes through a different one.

Comment: Wow. Didn't know to use those extra descriptors. First I was a bit confused (I like to understand what I run -- and got a bit confused with the curly braces). But now it's clear -- and IMHO exactly what the OP wanted. So +1 from me :)

Comment: This helped me. I wanted to add more data into stderr. This does that and properly outputs everything back on stdout/stderr. `{ { { { echo "stdout" ; echo "stderr">&2; } 2>&3; } 3>&1 1>&2 | awk '{print "ERROR:",$0}' 1>&3; } 3>&2 2>&1; }`

Answer (score 1):

You could just redirect stderr to a file and if anything shows up in it, it's from stderr.

e.g. 
`ls -a 2> ls-all.txt`

if there was an error for any reason sent to stderr, it will be redirected to this file.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this once off, redirect one of them somewhere else.

Example, redirecting standard out with `>`.

ls -al > ls-l.txt
(any output here is not from stdout, if you see anything it must be stderr output)

For stderr redirection use `2>`

Comment: The process creates a constant stream of output, some to stdout some to stderr.  I want to determine which is which as this output is going to the screen