# With bash, how to get 1 Line from xxhsum --version?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

With bash, how to get 1 Line from `xxhsum --version` ?

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Why unexpected bash results with
pipe `| head` and
pipe `| awk`  ?

Examples below work as expected:

`md5sum --version`

md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Ulrich Drepper, Scott Miller, and David Madore.

`md5sum --version | head -n1`
md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.30

`md5sum --version | head -n 1`
md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.30

`md5sum --version | awk 'NR==1'`
md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.30

But there is a faster hasher
xxhsum
i am testing it, also called
xxhash

`xxhsum --version`
xxhsum 0.8.1 by Yann Collet
compiled as 64-bit x86_64 autoVec little endian with GCC 9.3.0

All the above is as expected.
But unexpected results with:

`xxhsum --version | head -n1`
xxhsum 0.8.1 by Yann Collet
compiled as 64-bit x86_64 autoVec little endian with GCC 9.3.0

`xxhsum --version | head -n 1`
xxhsum 0.8.1 by Yann Collet
compiled as 64-bit x86_64 autoVec little endian with GCC 9.3.0

`xxhsum --version | awk 'NR==1'`
xxhsum 0.8.1 by Yann Collet
compiled as 64-bit x86_64 autoVec little endian with GCC 9.3.0

unexpected results because
2 Lines are printed to screen, not 1 Line.

Regarding xxhsum ...
How come 2 Lines are printed to screen?

How to get `1` Line printed from
`xxhsum --version`  ?

--

Comment: If `xxhsum --version 2>&1 | head -n1` does not solve the problem then please leave me a comment and I will reopen the question.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Determine if output is stdout or stderr](https://superuser.com/q/453598/432690).

Comment: Kamil' answer:     
```xxhsum --version 2>&1 | head -n1```   
gives desired 1 Line output     
```xxhsum 0.8.1 by Yann Collet```   

and   

the provided web page -- how to Determine if output is stdout or stderr with   
```{ { xxhsum --version; } 2>&3 | sed 's/^/STDOUT: /'; } 3>&1 1>&2 | sed 's/^/STDERR: /'```    
gives an answer stating STDERR meaning:    
```STDERR: xxhsum 0.8.1 by Yann Collet```     
```STDERR: compiled as 64-bit x86_64 autoVec little endian with GCC 9.3.0```  .